# HighchartView inside RecyclerView or NestedScrollView causes laggy scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, highcharts, scroll, android-nestedscrollview

When i place HIChartView(From HighCharts library) inside NestedScrollView or RecyclerView and try to scroll up the page by touching on the chartView, the recyclerview scroll movement is very laggy.
This is happening only when i touch the chartview and try to scroll the page up. But the recyclerview scroll is smooth when i touch outside of the chartview and move the page up.

When the tooltip is visible on chart and user tries to scroll, then the lag is more evident and annoying.

HIChartView extends RelativeLayout

Tried following two ways, both did not work

1)In nested scroll view

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nsv_view_trend"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@color/background_interface_secondary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/cv_footer"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cl_header">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

       <com.highsoft.highcharts.core.HIChartView
        android:id="@+id/trend_graph"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/chart_label" 
       />

        <FooterView
            android:id="@+id/privacy_policy_footer_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/space_16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/space_24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/space_16dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            tools:visibility="visible" />
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

2)As an item in recyclerView

Any ideas on how to solve this issue ?

Comment: Hi, could you share a sample of your code?

Comment: @SebastianHajdus Updated the question with sample code.